# Error in options when writing filterType API in options for mui-datatables, using typescript

Tags: reactjs, react-typescript, mui-datatable

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { UseCovid19, Cases } from "./UseCovid19";
import "./Covid19.css";
import MUIDataTable from "mui-datatables";
import { createMuiTheme, MuiThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { Checkbox } from "@material-ui/core";

export const Covid19 = () => {
  const { error, isLoaded, items } = UseCovid19();

  const columns = [
    {
      name: "specimen_collection_date",
      label: "Specimen Collection Date",
      options: {
        filter: true,
        sort: true,
      },
    },
    {
      name: "case_disposition",
      label: "Case Disposition",
      option: {
        filter: true,
        sort: true,
      },
    },
    {
      name: "transmission_category",
      label: "Transmission Category",
      option: {
        filter: true,
        sort: true,
      },
    },
    {
      name: "case_count",
      label: "Case Count",
      option: {
        filter: true,
        sort: true,
      },
    },
  ];

  const options = {
    filterType: "checkbox",
  };

  if (error) {
    return <div>Error: {error}</div>;
  } else if (!isLoaded) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  } else {
    return (
      <div className="myTable">
        <MUIDataTable
          title={"Employee List"}
          data={items}
          columns={columns}
          options={options}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

There is an error in the `options={options}` when i insert filterType="Checkbox" it give me this error

Type '{ filterType: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<{ caseSensitive: boolean; confirmFilters: boolean; count: number; customFilterDialogFooter: (filterList: any[], applyNewFilters?: ((...args: any[]) => any) | undefined) => ReactNode; ... 76 more ...; viewColumns: boolean; }>'.
Types of property 'filterType' are incompatible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should install the type definitions `@types/mui-datatables` and declare the correct type on `options`.

```js
import MUIDataTable, { MUIDataTableOptions } from 'mui-datatables';

const options: MUIDataTableOptions = {
  filterType: 'checkbox',
};
```

Answer (score -1):

alright I solved it i need to defined a type for the property apperantly using `filterType: "checkbox" as any`